# What's the correct way of typing an error in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I want to be able to provide a custom error (properly typed) to react-query's `useQuery` hook. The reason for this custom error is to be able to provide to it the `status` code of the response in case it fails, so I can determine whether or not to use the `useErrorBoundary` option based on that status.

I've read that it's not a very good idea to provide generics to `useQuery` like so:

```
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery<DataType, CustomErrorType>(
  ['example'],
  () => getData(),
  {
    useErrorBoundary: (error) => error.status >= 500
  }
)
```

And that it's a better idea to let react-query infer the types by typing the `queryFn` instead. If I were using `axios` this wouldn't be an issue since it provides some utilities and types for errors, but I'm working with `fetch`.

So, what would be the best way to get a correctly typed custom error in this case?

Comment: It's fine to explicitly define types for `data` and `error`, see https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/typescript#typing-the-error-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `Error` type can be inferred from all "places", so it works if you provide a type annotation to `useErrorBoundary`:

```
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(
  ['example'],
  () => getData(),
  {
    useErrorBoundary: (error: CustomErrorType) => error.status >= 500
  }
)
```

this will make the type of `Data` still be inferred from the queryFn (and eliminate all other problems that come from passing generics manually), and `error` will still be `CustomErrorType`

[TypeScript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCKz1QJ5wC+cAZlBCHAOQACMAhgHaoMDGA1gPRTr2swBaAI458VAFDjWEZvADm6GABF6DOAF44ACgCUGgHxwACuRDAMAOh6oIAGwBu6LQFYdkmHjDo4AYTQwKAFEocigAFU9vTSQWVTQALjhGZBAAI1wiSWlZRDgAE1V6ABo4cwAZCHo84EY5EtxQog0UDGxcPC1xODgAbSp0AA96cFt0KgBdIq7tPXVDBWVC3SnuhGnutHRg0IAhCGRGAvxErQboRL8WIJDoCK9ZwzOoC1iYNDh9TWcABm-pwnEbnET3EnE4cAAegB+cQFBig8HQoA)